# How to unit test a function that returns nothing (but assigns values to variables)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jestjs

How do you unit test functions that **don't return** anything, but **do** change variables' values?

I've looked through many S.O. questions to try and find an answer; here are a couple slightly-educated guesses:

1. Inside Jest's test(), run the function and then check to see if `variable = expectedValue`
2. This use-case doesn't require unit testing, it's a simple variable assignment
3. Rewrite the function specifically so that it returns something
4. Function shouldn't exist if it's not returning anything, just put the initialization code in parent function

1 seems like the best answer; 2 could be right - I'm new and still figuring out *what exactly* needs to be tested; 3 feels like overkill for some use-cases; 4 can't always be right, sometimes you just need to split out functionality if only for readability.

---

**My specific use-case:**

`initializeGame` is called within the `playGame` function. It doesn't return anything; it just sets some variables to their start conditions (player X's turn, empty board, etc.) How can I test that `gameTracker` was set to `[]`, for example?

```
let gameTracker = [], turn;
const turnX = 'X', turnO = 'O';

function playGame() {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    initializeGame();

    $('.square').click(function () {
      makeMove($(this));
      endTurn();
    });
  });
}
function initializeGame() {
  $('.start').css('display', 'none');
  $('.square').children('p').text('');
  gameTracker = [];
  turn = turnX;
  $('h1').text('Player ' + turn + ' Turn');
}
```

**And the test:**

```
const tictactoe = require('./tictactoe');

test('gameTracker should equal [] after running initializeGame()', () => {
    tictactoe.initializeGame();
    expect(gameTracker).toBe([]);
})
```

Comment: Generally a unit test's primary goal is to ensure the code behaves a certain way according to _outside callers_. You should be able to totally change out the internals of the class without breaking the tests, as long as it appears to behave the same way. If users of this code care about some state, they should have ways to read it, and your test should use that interface to check that the state is correct. But more likely, this internal data isn't something you will benefit from building a test around. Instead, you can test for outward symptoms of malfunction.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Yes, this function doesn't have outside callers as you describe them. So for my use case, an outward symptom of malfunction could be: after initializing a new game, one move is made - if the board DOESN'T only have one X in it, it means the initialization failed? The problem with this is that the error could potentially come from two sources: the initialization function, or the makeMove function: maybe this would make it an integration test vs. a unit test, right?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you cannot test for inside variable value

However you should unit test with "external" results it produces.
So you could theoritically change the internal of your fonction during a refactor without having to change your tests.

So set your variable, run your function and test the updated value of your variable